# cloud-init .yaml script on Digital Ocean droplets

Tags: ssh-keys, digital-ocean, cloud-init

I am stuck with creating users with Cloud-Config.

Did anyone succeed and can share a .yaml gist to create a new user with ssh-authorized-keys and ability to sudo?

Comment: More of us here;https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/cloud-config-on-cents-not-working-at-all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This article on DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-cloud-config-for-your-initial-server-setup) runs through doing some of the most common initial tasks using cloud-config files.

Setting up a new sudo user would look like this:

```
#cloud-config
users:
  - name: username
    ssh-authorized-keys:
      - ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQCv60WjxoM39LgPDbiW7ne3gu18q0NIVv0RE6rDLNal1quXZ3nqAlANpl5qmhDQ+GS/sOtygSG4/9aiOA4vXO54k1mHWL2irjuB9XbXr00+44vSd2q/vtXdGXhdSMTf4/XK17fjKSG/9y3yD6nml6 user@example.com
    sudo: ['ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL']
    groups: sudo
    shell: /bin/bash
```

Of course, replace the ssh key with your public key.